# A question from floating point number representation.

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, number-systems, floating-point

The numbers in a floating-point system are defined by a base B, a mantissa length t, and an
exponent range [L, U]. A nonzero floating-point number x has the form

x = +/-(o.b1b2.....bt)B^e ---1

then how to prove

x = +/-( b1 + b2/(B) + b3/(B^2).......+bt/(B^(t-l)))B^e  ---2

I'm actually confused about the relationship between these two equations. I tried to understand it for several days but I couldn't. Can you explain this? Is there any fault with these equations?

Comment: Your writing is rather unclear.  Note that l is not $1$.  Are ---1 and ---2 just equation numbers?  What is $e$?

Comment: You are right --1 and --2 are equation numbers. and e is the exponent that L<=e<=U.

Answer (score 0):

If you assume $B=10$ and think about the place values of a decimal it will probably become clear.  The significance of each digit is divided by the base because it is one position lower.  It looks like you are one power of $B$ off because $b_1$ is behind the decimal point in the first.

Comment: Assume B = 10 and e = 3 ,Then from equation 1 we can get b1b2b3.b4....bt  and form equation 2 we can get b1b2b3b4.b5....bt . But these two values are inequal.It seem to be one of this equation is wrong.isnt it.

Comment: So write it out.  The first is $x=\pm 0.b_1b_2b_3$.  The second is $x=\pm(b_1+\frac {b_2}{10}+\frac {b_3}{100})$.  Doesn't that look like decimal expansion, but off by one factor of $10$?